# EnvelopedCms Encryption: maintain length of encrypted message

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I have a problem encrypting with EnvelopedCms class.

Incoming message is strictly array with length 4096. I expect that same length in encrypted output but I get different values all the time.

I need to limit output length to 4096. Is there A way I get control over this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there A way I get control over this?

No. There isn't.

The `EnvelopedCms` class internally creates a random symmetric key, uses this key to encrypt the content and then encrypts this symmetric key once for each certificate you provide. The encrypted symmetric keys with the corresponding certificate identifiers (Issuer of certificate and serial number of the certificate or the Subject Key Identifier of the certificate) will be stored in the output as headers. There are also other headers (See [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652)).

Since [symmetric encryption output is always larger or equal to the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055078/aes-output-is-it-smaller-than-input), adding the headers guarantees that the output is larger than the input.